# How to run Jenkins pipeline as a user?

Tags: windows, jenkins, build

Trying to setup Multibranch Pipeline, but my build runs as "System". I need my build to run as specific user.

I've installed "Authorized Project" plugin, but I do not see "Authorization" page in project and cannot set user to build. If I set "Run as User" in security settings, build runs as anonymous.

I use Jenkins with Windows Server 2016.

How do I set user for a project build? Do I have to use steps with 'runas' or something?

Comment: You can set a different user through the settings of the Jenkins Windows service. Task Manager > Services > Jenkins > Properties.

Comment: Yeah, it helps. Thanks!